# How to preprocess rows in MS Excel to create series data based on common column values

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have several hundred rows of data where one column contains students names, one column contains an assignment ID, and one column contains scores. I am looking for way in MS Excel to preprocess the data set, either using built in functions or VB macros in such a way to organize the scores into a series labeled by the students name.  If possible I would like to use assignment id’s for y axis labels when I graph.  Is there a macro or function for preprocessing data like this in MS Excel?

```
     A.        B.         C. 
1   Name      ID         Score
2   Al        1000       97%
3   Rob       1000       93%
4   Jack      1000       95% 
5   Al        1001       92%
6   Rob       1001       97%
7   Tim       1001       98%
8   Jack      1001       93%
```

Transforms to

```
 A.         B.         C. 
1 Name       1000      1001
2 Al         97%       92%
3 Rob        93%       97%
4 Jack       95%       93%
5 Tim                  98%
```

Comment: Please post sample data with desired output. As of now, I've no idea what the formula should do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update：
Try to insert a [PivotTable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576).
[image]

Comment: That worked great.

Answer (score 0):

### Pivot Column (VBA Solution)

- The first column contains the row labels (R). You want to pivot the second column that contains the column labels (C). The third column contains the values (V).
- This solution will cover the previous, which often may appear in different flavors e.g. you may want to pivot the first column, there are several row labels or column labels, the values are in another column, you may want to sum if there are duplicates, etc. Therefore I suggest you investigate another simple way (besides the `PivotTable`) to do this using `PowerQuery` (previously `Get & Transform`) with a ton of options.
- Adjust (play with) the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PivotRCV()
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirst As String = "A1"
    
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirst As String = "E1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Range ('srg').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = RefColumns(sws.Range(sFirst).Resize(, 3))
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' empty columns, not even headers
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    If srCount = 1 Then Exit Sub ' only headers, no data
    
    ' Write the unique row labels to the Row Labels Array ('rLabels').
    Dim srrg As Range
    Set srrg = srg.Columns(1).Resize(srCount - 1).Offset(1)
    Dim rLabels As Variant: rLabels = ArrUniqueColumnRange(srrg)
    If IsEmpty(rLabels) Then Exit Sub ' only error values and/or blanks
    
    ' Write the unique column labels to the Column Labels Array ('cLabels').
    Dim scrg As Range
    Set scrg = srg.Columns(2).Resize(srCount - 1).Offset(1)
    Dim cLabels As Variant: cLabels = ArrUniqueColumnRange(scrg)
    If IsEmpty(cLabels) Then Exit Sub ' only error values and/or blanks
 
    ' Write values from the Source Range to the Source Array ('sData').
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    ' Define the Destination Array ('dData').
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = UBound(rLabels) + 2 ' both +1 - zero-based...
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = UBound(cLabels) + 2 ' ... +1 - headers
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)

    ' Write to Destination Array.
    dData(1, 1) = sData(1, 1) ' First (Row Label) Header
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To drCount - 2 ' Row Labels
        dData(n + 2, 1) = rLabels(n)
    Next n
    For n = 0 To dcCount - 2 ' Column Labels
        dData(1, n + 2) = cLabels(n)
    Next n
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    For n = 2 To srCount ' Values
        r = Application.Match(sData(n, 1), rLabels, 0) + 1
        c = Application.Match(sData(n, 2), cLabels, 0) + 1
        dData(r, c) = sData(n, 3)
    Next n

    ' Create a reference to the Destination Range ('drg').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(dFirst).Resize(drCount, dcCount)
    
    ' Write to the Destination Range.
    'drg.Clear
    drg.Value = dData
    
    ' Format the Destination Range.
    With drg.Rows(1) ' Headers
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    With drg.Resize(drCount - 1, dcCount - 1).Offset(1, 1) ' Values
        .NumberFormat = "0%"
    End With
    
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox sData(1, 2) & " column pivoted successfully.", _
        vbInformation, "Pivot RCV"

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the range from a row range
'               ('FirstRowRange') to the row range containing
'               the bottom-most non-empty cell in the given row's columns.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumns( _
    ByVal FirstRowRange As Range) _
As Range
    If FirstRowRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With FirstRowRange.Rows(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function ' empty range
        Set RefColumns = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the unique values of a one-column range in an array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function ArrUniqueColumnRange( _
    ColumnRange As Range) _
As Variant
    If ColumnRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    With ColumnRange.Columns(1)
        rCount = .Rows.Count
        If rCount = 1 Then
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            Data = .Value
        End If
    End With
    
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        Dim Key As Variant
        Dim r As Long
        For r = 1 To rCount
            Key = Data(r, 1)
            If Not IsError(Key) Then
                If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                    .Item(Key) = Empty
                End If
            End If
        Next r
        If .Count = 0 Then Exit Function ' only error values and/or blanks
        ArrUniqueColumnRange = .Keys
    End With

End Function
```